# Django: How to apply the built-in password validators?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, password-protection

I like to test the django built-in validators on my registration form. So i added this...

---

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'min_length': 9,
        }
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

---

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
import django.contrib.auth.password_validation as validators


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')


    # --- check duplicate
    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']

    # --- django built-in validator
    def pass_validate(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data('password')
        try:
            validators(password, self.instance)
        except forms.ValidationError as error:
            self.add_error('password', error)
        return password
```

---

**views.py**

```
<...>
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object but avoid saving it yet
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            # Set the chosen password
            new_user.set_password(
                user_form.cleaned_data['password'])
            # Save the User object
            new_user.save()
            return render(request,
                          'account/register_done.html',
                          {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request,
                  'account/register.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form})
<...>
```

---

- Unfortunately i can still register as a user with passwords like "123". So *the min_length* does not work.
- The `pass_validate` Function in forms.py was an approach, to add the django built-in validators, after reading some articles here in the forum.
- The good thing is the server works and shows no errors.

So my question is *" How to apply the built-in password validators"* in the right way? Do i need i a special validators.py ? But my guess i got the function in forms.py wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at the built-in auth forms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms ? Maybe you can use one of them for your task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `UserCreationForm` so that your `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` would work.

For example:

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Email Already Exists')

        return email

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('some_view')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'template', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Alright so the built-in `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS` are connected with  `UserCreationForm`. Works,now i understand, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Like other model validation, password validation needs to be explicitly called. You can trigger password validation by calling `validate_password` directly.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password',
                               widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')

    # --- django built-in validator
    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        validate_password(password)
        return password

    # --- check duplicate
    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match.')
        return cd['password2']
```

You can pass `validate_password` individual validators if you don't wan to use all of the defaults. See `help(validate_password)`.